# How do I install/enable the uuid-ossp extension on Postgres 9.3?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, uuid, postgresql-extensions

I’m using Postgres 9.3 on Ubuntu Linux 14.04.  How do I install/enable the uuid-ossp extension?  I first verified the contrib package was installed …

```
root@prodbox:/home/rails/myproject# apt-get install postgresql-contrib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-contrib is already the newest version.
```

and then I logged in and tried to create the extension …

```
root@prodbox:/home/rails/myproject# su - postgres
postgres@prodbox:~$ psql
psql (9.6.0, server 9.3.11)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory
```

I’m all out of ideas.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have two versions (9.6 and 9.3) installed (because the `psql` version is 9.6).  Because the `postgresql-contrib` package automatically defaults to the currently supported PostgreSQL database contrib package (as noted if you do apt-cache show postgresql-contrib), you'll have to install the contrib package for 9.3:

```
apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.3
```

Comment: also works when creating a Docker image of Postgres 9.3.  Just add -y to the command so it installs without asking for confirmation

Answer (score 4):

These steps worked for me in my centos 7, when I was facing this issue in my postgres 12,

1. `sudo yum install postgresql-contrib-12`
2. `sudo su - postgres` or whatever your username for postgres is
3. `psql` to enter into postgresql cli commands line
4. `CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";`

Comment: Use `postgresql14-contrib`